# what are the procedure to follow to setup Oracle SSL in Orale env

Tags: oracle, ssl, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

what is the procedure to follow to setup SSL in oracle env.

for windows and linux both need to setup SSL configuration in Oracle and Linnux env setup.

Comment: Did you check the Database Administration Guide (at least in its [2Day version](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admqs/index.html))?

Comment: [You already asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71346089/266304). If you don't get a response then improve your original question with details of what you have and need to achieve - 'setup SSL' is rather vague - and consider if this is an appropriate site; one of the other Stack Exchange network of sites might be better, depending on exactly what you need to know.

Comment: On windows Oracle server how can i setup SSL.